# Remote Connection to PostgreSQL in a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: linux, postgresql, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 2 with Debian Jessie OS. I want to connect remotely to postgresql in it.

I installed postgresql with command below:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Then I set a password for postgres user:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Added below line to /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf

```
host  all  all 192.168.1.0/24 md5
```

and below line to /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Finally I restarted postgresql service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

But when I tried to connect to postgresql server from another pc in 192.168.1.0/24 network I get "server doesn't listen" error from pgadmin.

Also when I use "netstat -an | grep 5432" command, there is nothing.

result of "sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status" is:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2016-02-20 15:22:22 UTC; 50min ago
  Process: 21070 ExecReload=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21119 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21119 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 20 15:22:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 15:22:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

So I cant get the problem. Is it about Debian Jessie OS or raspberry pi 2 or another thing?

I have just done same things in an Ubuntu machine and everything is fine.

Comment: Looks like the postmaster fails to start up. Maybe the installation proces failed at initdb, or the data directory is not present / wrong owner. Check the logfile and maybe syslog.

Comment: I checked postgresql log file. Problem is about insufficient disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar problem wherein I get an error message saying "unable to connect to server" when i try to connect through my laptop.

The precise error message is 
Unable to connect to server:

FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.2.6", user "vivek", database "vivekdb", SSL off
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.2.6", user "vivek", database "vivekdb", SSL on

I have followed the exact same steps stated above.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but for some reason I ended up here too. I beleive the fix for this is to change the IPV4 and IPV6 addresses in the pg_hba config file /etc/postgresql/XX/main/pg_hba.conf to:

```
127.0.0.1/32 to 0.0.0.0/0 for IPv4 
::1/128 to ::/0 for IPv6
```

Comment: Nope, with configuration I'm not able to connect to the DB from the same device